# How do i suggest a password to user in a form

Tags: html, node.js

Some days behind I created a new account in a service and it shown me a suggested password in the input

How can i do it with javascript in my page?

Comment: Don't? Any password not created by the user themselves, or the browser they use, or a password manager they installed, is not a secure password.

Comment: yes, but its those passwords which combine upper and lower case letters, simbols and numbers

Comment: Okay? Still not something to do in JS, let the browser handle it (all browsers let you view saved logins).